# How to get the value of a specific element

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

If I inspect an element which is in the form of

```
<div data-name="Salesforce Integration" data-category-"other" data-description "Salesforce Integration" data-is-defined-"true" id="sc13677-15" class="sc-view sc-collection-item hidden-campaign-element-view sc-regular-size" style="left: 566px; wid th: 240px; top: 381px; height: 54px">

<div class="count">8</div>
```

how to get the value 8 using Selenium C#?

I have tried using below method:

```
//Getting text from element
public string GetTextFromElement(IWebElement element) 
{ 
    Log.Debug($"{_BrowserName) {element.Text}"); 
    return element.Text;
}
```

But is returning null.

This is the XPath query I have used:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class="count"]");
```

Comment: How do you get the `emement`? It feels like the problem is there. Please edit the question and paste your code so we can analyze it.